# Can you use a lookup column to filter results in a content search webpart?

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, content-search-web-part

I am working on a site in Sharepoint 2013 and I have created a content search webpart in a page layout used for multiple pages. I want to be able to display items from a list that are associated with a particular page. I created a lookup column on the items that reference the Pages library. I figured I could associate the value in the lookup field with the page title, but that does not appear to work. Is there a way to configure the query in the content search webpart to display items tagged with the value in the lookup field?

Currently I am trying to display items from a list that all have a lookup field that pulls the page Titles from the Pages list. I have set the query variable in the search webpart as 'lookup={Page.Title}' in the hopes that the query will match items in the list with the lookup value of the items. This is not pulling in results however.